# Android File Observer

Tags: android

I have created app that detects when otg cable is plugged in or when it's plugged out using fileobserver but for some reason it's not working!!!
Why app is not working?

App source code:

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Process suProcess;
    private static int conn_length = -1;
    File directory = new File("/sys/bus/usb/devices");
    File[] contents = directory.listFiles();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getRoot();



        FileObserver observer = new FileObserver("/sys/bus/usb/devices")
        {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, String file)
            {
                if(contents.length == conn_length){
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    conn_length = contents.length;
                }

                if(conn_length == 0)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"otg not connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"otg connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        observer.startWatching();
    }

    private void getRoot()
    {
        try
        {
            suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Files under /sys are not real files, and inotify, which is what FileObserver uses, does not work with them. If you used ndk you could use poll or select to get notified when devices are plugged in.

On a higher level, you can use a broadcast receiver to get notifications of USB devices https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html